# Car randomly fails to start up

Tags: toyota, corona

I've been having this recurring problem with my car. Whenever I leave it in the parking lot. It just no longer starts up.

I already replaced the battery and its still acting up.

The only way I can get the car to startup is when I press the relays till the fan suddenly switches on and stops or the headlights flickers or any sort of electrical activity when pressing the relays.

When I start the car it starts no problem. The issue seems to be intermittent sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

The car is a Toyota Corona 2.0 Ex

Comment: Can you describe what you see and hear while trying to start the engine? e.g. do you hear the starter motor running, are there lights on the dash......

Comment: The car has lights. And its not dimming or anything. My stereo is working fine. My power windows are working okay. 

The car just won't start. When I turn the key I hear a single clicking noise.

The only way I could get it to start was to press the relays or tap with it a screwdriver. After tapping the headlights will flicker and when I turn the key it starts back up.